# Как пишется нормандский формат?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, кавычки, названия

Как пишется словосочетание **нормандский формат**? Со строчной или с прописной? Заключается ли кавычки?

Аналогичный вопрос с астанинским, женевским и другими форматами переговоров.

Answer (score 2):

Из Википедии:

**«Нормандская четвёрка», «нормандский формат»** — дипломатическая группа высокопоставленных представителей четырёх стран (Германии, России, Украины и Франции) по урегулированию ситуации на востоке Украины...

Например: На уровне глав государств встречи в «нормандском формате » проходили три раза.

"Нормандский формат" — **нарицательное название**, которое определяет состав группы и условия проведения переговоров. Это не имя собственное, поэтому используется **строчная буква.**

**Кавычки** могут ставиться или нет, здесь они обозначают условность названия. Но со временем название становится привычным, и тогда кавычки можно не ставить.